# why are access modifies used so much in Java but not in C#?

Tags: java, c#

Namely, why is the Java main method public but the C# Main method is defaulted to internal? I also find that classes in C# often don't need to denote an access modifier but in Java we slave over ensuring visibility is restricted just to those that need to see the information of these other classes.

Comment: Java always defaults to package access, which promotes object-oriented encapsulation:  your own classes can see the class/member, but other packages cannot.

Answer (score 0):

In dotnet the `Main`method doesn't have to be `public`. It can be `private` inside a `private` class and the runtime will still be able to resolve it. You may want to change the modifiers on `Main` for your own reasons though.

You can find more detailed information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/

In general though dotnet developers do (or should) give the same amount of consideration to access modifiers as Java developers.